# in a virtual machine with ssd (solid state) hard drive how can create a hdd hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, vmware-workstation, nvme, scsi

in a virtual machine with ssd (solid state drive) can we create a hard disk with hdd (hard disk drive) type? i installed windows 10 on vmware workstation and its hard disk is nvme and ssd. i created another with type scsi but its type is also ssd. but i want to create a hard drive with hdd type. what should i do? is it possible at all?
edit:
i want to have both ssd and hdd
vmware version: 16.0.0 build-16894299

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve by using a virtual hdd configured as a HDD instead of a SSD?  What version of VMWare Workstation are you using?  What version of Windows 10 are you using?  Knowing this information will help write a better answer to your question.  You can [edit] your question to include this vital information required to answer your question.

Comment: @John my host machine has both ssd and hdd

Comment: @John - I suspect you don't understand what the author is asking.  They want to add a "HDD" to their VM instead of adding a "SSD" to their VM.  It shouldn't be necessary to use an actual HDD on the host to add a virtual hdd that is classified as a HDD instead of an SSD.  In fact, i know it isn't required, since my HDD only host for years had SSD virtual HDDs.

Comment: @John - You can mount partition of a physical drive to a VM.  I have done it before to test an ISO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the guest VM is created with the Windows operating system, this can be done from
inside the VM using the PowerShell command
[Set-PhysicalDisk](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/windows/powershell-scripting/hh848651(v=wps.630)):

- Run PowerShell as Administrator
- Enter either of the following commands:

  ```
    Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName PhysicalDisk# -MediaType HDD
    Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName PhysicalDisk# -MediaType SSD
  ```